# PHP Variable Variables to set a number as part of a variable name

Tags: php

Using PHP I have a Form that POSTS a `Text Line` from user input.

Each `text line` also has other data posted with it.  So each `text line` a user submits has this data:

- Text line string
- Text line color
- Text line font name

A user can submit anywhere from **1 to 6** `Text Lines` in the Form Post.

So in the backend PHP script I am trying to do something like this...

```
//Sign Text Lines
$numberOfTextLines = $this->getRequest()->getPost('count'); // 4

for ($line=1; $line <= $numberOfTextLines; $line++) {

    $line1Text = $this->getRequest()->getPost('line-1-text');
    $line1TextColor = $this->getRequest()->getPost('line-1-colorpicker');
    $line1TextFont = $this->getRequest()->getPost('line-1-font');

}
```

`$numberOfTextLines`holds the number of `Text Lines` the user submitted in the POST.

So with that number of lines, I want to loop over that number of times and setup a variable to hold the `Text Line string`, `color`, and `font` values for each line of text submitted.

In the example above it would be **4 lines of text**.  So it needs to loop 4 times and set the 3 variables for each line.  **4 lines of text x 3 variables = 12 variables set altogether**.

In other parts of my script, I should then easily be able to do something like this below to check if a text line exist or not and if so should be able to access it's values...

```
if(isset($line4Text) && $line4Text != ''){
    echo 'Line 4 Text: ' . $line4Text;
    echo 'Line 4 Text Color: ' . $line4TextColor;
    echo 'Line 4 Text Font: ' . $line4TextFont;
}else{
    $line4Text = '';
    $line4TextColor = '';
    $line4TextFont = '';
}
```

So you can see, I need to take a number that is stored in a variable `$numberOfTextLines` that can be any value between 1 and 6.

Based on the number, I need to loop that many times and setup 3 variables for each number.  Replacing the number in the Variable names with the number of the line.  So in the 3 variables below, the number 4 in the name would be replaced with the corresponding number based on the number in the loop iteration:

```
$line4Text
$line4TextColor
$line4TextFont
```

I am not sure how to do this but I think possibly something to do with `Variable Variables`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is exactly for what [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are used, you can just use this with curly syntax:

```
${"line". $line . "Text"} = $this->getRequest()->getPost('line-' . $line . '-text');
${"line" . $line . "TextColor"} = $this->getRequest()->getPost('line-' . $line . '-colorpicker');
${"line" . $line . "TextFont"} = $this->getRequest()->getPost('line-' . $line . '-font');
```

Comment: great I thought it was something simple like this but I couldn't seem to get the correct syntax.  I'm not used to using `{`and `}` like that so that seems to be the trick, thanks!